# How to hide api key within script src with dotenv

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, dotenv

I am trying to hide my api key for google maps so I can push my code, but can't seem to get the process.env.API_KEY variable to work.  Is this possible to do?  I've tried concatenating with quotes and using back-ticks with template literals and can't seem to get it to work.

```
    function initMap() {
        let lat = <%= data.coord.lat%>;
        let lng =   <%= data.coord.lon%>;
        let center = {lat: lat, lng: lng };
        console.log(lat, lng);
        let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
              zoom: 8,
              center: center,
              scrollwheel: false
          });
        let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: center,
              map: map
          });
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        };

</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=process.env.API_KEY&callback=initMap
"></script>
```

My .env file has:

```
API_KEY = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create your script tag with some javascript :

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.defer = true;
script.async = true;
script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.API_KEY}&callback=initMap`;
document.appendChild(script);
```

But you will need a bundler like webpack to transpile it correctly.
I leave you with this link : https://www.robertcooper.me/front-end-javascript-environment-variables

Hope it helps.